# CGI script is not executable

Tags: python, http, webserver, cgi

In one of my homework practices, I must start a webserver and when I access webserver's root, it executes a CGI script.

But when I open localhost:8080, this error message appears:

```
Error code 403.

Message: CGI script is not executable ('/cgi-bin/todolist.cgi').

Error code explanation: 403 = Request forbidden -- authorization will not help.
```

My server code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import getopt
import logging
import BaseHTTPServer
from CGIHTTPServer import CGIHTTPRequestHandler
import json
from DBBackend import TodoDao

# CRUD to REST conventions
# POST   Create
# GET    Retrieve
# PUT    Update
# DELETE Delete

"""
API REST del servidor.

GET /todos        - Recupera la lista de tareas (ToDos)
DELETE /todos/id  - Elimina la tarea con el id especificado
POST /todos       - Añade una nueva tarea con los valores especificados como parámetros
PUT /todos/id     - Actualiza los valores espcificados en los parámetros para la tarea con
                    el id dado

Tanto los parámetros (en el cuerpo de la petición) como las respuestas son en formato JSON.
"""

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

class RESTHTTPRequestHandler(CGIHTTPRequestHandler):

    dao = TodoDao()
    res_string = dao.tableName
    res_path = "/" + res_string

    def _GET(self):
        if self.path == self.res_path:
            tasks = self.dao.findTasks()
            return {'code': 'ok', 'data': tasks}
        else:
            _,res,id = self.path.split("/")
            int(id)
            assert(res==self.res_string)
            data = self.dao.retrieveTask(id)
            return {'code': 'ok', 'data': data}

    def _POST(self):
        assert(self.path == self.res_path)
        if 'Content-length' in self.headers:
            data = json.loads(self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-length'])))
        else:
            data = json.load(self.rfile)
        self.dao.createTask(data)
        return {'code': 'ok'}


    def _PUT(self):
        _,res,id = self.path.split("/")
        int(id)
        assert(res==self.res_string)
        if 'Content-length' in self.headers:
            data = json.loads(self.rfile.read(int(self.headers['Content-length'])))
        else:
            data = json.load(self.rfile)
        self.dao.updateTask(id, data)
        return {'code': 'ok'}


    def _DELETE(self):
        _,res,id = self.path.split("/")
        int(id)
        assert(res==self.res_string)
        self.dao.deleteTask(id)
        return {'code': 'ok'}


    def _send(self, data):
        response = json.dumps(data)
        self.send_response(200)
        self.send_header("Content-type", "application/json")
        self.send_header("Content-Length", len(response))
        self.end_headers()
        self.wfile.write(response)


    # El BaseHTTPRequestHandler no está pensado para ésto :(
    def do_POST(self):
        self._reroute()
    def do_PUT(self):
        self._reroute()
    def do_GET(self):
        self._reroute()
    def do_DELETE(self):
        self._reroute()
    def _reroute(self):
        try:
            if self.path.startswith(self.res_path):
                method_name = '_' + self.command
                method = getattr(self, method_name)
                try:
                    self._send(method())
                except (ValueError, AssertionError):
                    self.send_error(400, "Invalid request")
                except:
                    logging.exception("Database access error")
                    self.send_error(500, "DDBB error")
            else:
                if self.path == "/" or self.path == "/index.html":
                    self.path = "/cgi-bin/todolist.cgi"
                method_name = 'do_' + self.command
                method = getattr(CGIHTTPRequestHandler, method_name)
                method(self)
        except AttributeError:
            self.send_error(501, "Unsupported method (%r)" % self.command)


#---- Defaults
port = "8080"
basedir = "www/"
#----

#----------------------------------------
def usage():
    print "Uso: " +  os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]) + " -h -p port"
    print "     -h         Muestra este mensaje"
    print "     -p port    Sirve en el puerto indicado (def={0})".format(port)
    print "     -d dirname Sirve el contenido del directorio indicado (def={0})".format(basedir)

#----------------------------------------

try:
    opts, args = getopt.getopt(sys.argv[1:], "hp:d:", ["help", "port=", "dir="])
except getopt.GetoptError:
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)

for o, a in opts:
    if o in ("-h", "--help"):
        usage()
        sys.exit()
    if o in ("-p", "--port"):
        port = a
    if o in ("-d", "--dir"):
        basedir = a

if (port == None):
    usage()
    sys.exit()

try:
    address = ('', int(port))
except ValueError:
    usage()
    sys.exit(2)

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(address,
                                  RESTHTTPRequestHandler)
os.chdir(basedir)
httpd.serve_forever()
```

And my todolist.cgi:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import cgi
import sys
import os
import datetime
import locale
# TBD: Usar el locale del cliente
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_TIME,'')
date_format = locale.nl_langinfo(locale.D_FMT)

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "../.."))
import DBBackend

print "Content-Type: text/html"
print ""
print """
<!doctype html>

<html lang="es">

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<title>[IPM] Lista de tareas</title>
<meta name="author" content="David Cabrero"/>
<meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1,maximun-scale=1,user-scalable=no"/>

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=ecdge,chrome=1">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
  <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/default.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/wide-screen.css" 
      media="only screen and (min-width : 1024px)" />
<script src="js/todolist.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<header>
<h1>ToDo</h1>
</header>

<ul>
"""
fname = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "../", DBBackend.DATABASEFILENAME)
li = """
  <a href="#dialog"><li data-task-id="{0}">
    <p class="desc">{1}</p>
    <time datetime="{2}">{3}</time>
    <p class="done" data-task-done="{4}">{5}</p>
  </li></a>
"""
for task in DBBackend.TodoDao(fname).findTasks():
    id = str(task['id'])
    desc = task['desc'].encode('utf-8')
    deadline = datetime.datetime.strptime(task['deadline'], "%Y-%m-%d")
    done = task['done'] == 1
    print li.format(id, desc, deadline.strftime("%Y-%m-%d"), deadline.strftime(date_format),
                    "yes" if done else "no", "Hecho" if done else "Sin hacer")

print """
</ul>


<div id="updateTask" class="dialog"><div>
  <h1>Actualizar tarea</h1>
  <form>
    <p><input type="text" name="task_desc" placeholder="task description" autofocus="autofocus" /></p>
    <p><input type="date" name="task_deadline" placeholder="deadline" /></p>
    <p><input type="checkbox" name="task_done" /></p>
    <p class="okCancel">
      <button name="ok">OK</button> 
      <button name="cancel">Cancel</button>
    </p>
  </form>
</div></div>

</body>

</html>
"""

print """
"""
```

All the code was given by teachers (I have to do a web application), so I don't know how to start if I cannot manage to get the server working. I'm also running Windows 7 and Python for Windows (Version 2.7), hope it helps!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, what you need to do to make this work under Windows is to rename your script from todolist.cgi to todolist.py and change the line in server code where it says:

```
self.path = "/cgi-bin/todolist.cgi"
```

change that to:

```
self.path = "/cgi-bin/todolist.py"
```

That should let it all work in Windows without too much fuss.  It all has to do with the inner workings of CGIHTTPServer and how it handles executables.  I tried various other tricks (and outright hacks like monkey-patching CGIHTTPServer.executable...) to make it work, but this seemed the simplest.

Comment: Thanks! I managed to execute the script correctly, but now some sort of problem with locale appears... I suppose I'll have to work my way through it. Thanks again for the answer, though ;)

Answer (score 6):

The problem is not in your code, but in the filesystem permissions. The cgi file must be marked execuatable. This can be done with `chmod a+x todolist.cgi`, from a shell in the cgi-bin directory.

Comment: That's a great answer for Unix or unix-like systems...  But no matter how hard you bang your head against the keyboard, Windows 7 just doesn't seem to grok that `chmod` thing.